# Crate-level visibility

Tags: interface, rust, encapsulation

I have two types, each with a bunch of supporting functions; the entire content of these two types should be private (in my case, they are mutable pointers to objects in C). These two types are conceptually different, so I put them in different modules…

```
pub mod client {
    pub struct Client {
        // private internals
    }
    // Lots of code.
}
pub mod collection {
    pub struct Collection {
        // private internals
    }
    // Lots of code.
}
```

(In my real-world case, `mod client` and `mod collection` are separate files, i.e., `client.rs` and `collection.rs`.)

`client.rs` needs to create a `Collection`; however, it can't, because the internals are private. Any attempt to write a function suffers the same problem: the function would need to be in `collection.rs` (to access the private members of `Collection`, but would need to be `pub` so that `client.rs` can access it… but now it's also `pub` to the entire world.

What I'd really like is some sort of crate-level visibility, or a way to "friend" this struct out to another module. (Otherwise, the `pub`lically visible stuff in the crate doesn't represent the API, which seems silly.)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3):

Move `Collection` to a new private module (e.g. `collection_impl`). Add a public function in that module to create a `Collection`. Re-export `Collection` from `collection` (which is public) with `pub use`.

You can use `collection_impl` from within your crate, but since it is private, other crates cannot use it. However, by re-exporting `Collection` in module `collection`, other crates can use `Collection` through this path.

```rust
pub mod client {
    use super::collection;
    use super::collection_impl;

    pub struct Client {
        p: i32
    }

    /* this could also be a method on Client */
    pub fn make_collection(client: &Client) -> collection::Collection {
        collection_impl::new_collection(42)
    }
}

mod collection_impl {
    pub struct Collection {
        p: i32
    }

    pub fn new_collection(p: i32) -> Collection {
        Collection { p: p }
    }
}

pub mod collection {
    use super::collection_impl;
    pub use collection_impl::Collection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you compare Rust and C++ you will notice that Rust does not have:

- `protected`
- `friend`

This is a deliberate design, and there is no alternative. In Rust something is either private or public, and therefore you do not have to jump all around the codebase to know whether an invariant holds or not.

Therefore, the solution is to:

- make a `pub fn new` function to create a `Collection`
- reinforce this function so it is perfectly safe to use by the whole world

This is actually good design; if there is *one* `struct` that should be responsible for upholding `Collection`'s invariants, it certainly is `Collection` itself. Delegating this responsibility to another crate seems hazardous.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but will point out that there is also the possibility of marking the function as `unsafe`, which might discourage consumers from calling the method. You could also make the method public but mark it as `#[doc(hidden)]`.